# Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Please Guys help me, I am developing asp.net application, on OS: 64 bit(Windows 10), I have created my application on Visual Studio Community 2015.

I have added Crystal Reports, I downloaded Crystal Report for Visual Studio, and CCRuntime 64 bit, my app is running on my local machine, once I publish I get this error:

> "Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An
>   error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to
>   load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry
>   key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is
>   not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal
>   Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version
>   of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required. 
>   Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more
>   information.]
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime()
>   +230    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +159
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception.]
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +0
>   Axucollections.statementOfAccount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in C:\Users\wisem\Desktop\Collection
>   System\Axucollections\Axucollections\statementOfAccount.aspx.cs:25
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +678"

I have tried most of the solutions I have found online, like changing the appPool (Enable 32 Bit Application) to True on IIS, also tried change my app on VS from Any CPU to x86, no luck also to x64 still no luck.

I have also went to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
and comment out the lines that says: 
         -->

still no luck, I have never done Crystal Reports before, I know somehow that something I am missing.

please help me to solve this

Comment: Please copy the text into your question, as quote. Many people won't click on a link just to see an error.

Comment: Is it possible to publish Crystal Report created in Visual Stdio. ASP.NET Website into Azure?